# Zend fancybox login doesn't work properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework, fancybox

I am using zend and fancybox for the popup login form, but it works perfect, the problem is when I login. It reload the fancybox and not the current parent page. So, when I login into, it actually inside that login form box that show the user page. So, I want when submit is press it log with the parent page instead of the fancybox.

here's my code:

javascript fancybox:

```
$('a.iframe').fancybox({
        width   : 520, 
        height  : 300,
        type    : 'iframe',
        scrolling: 'no',
        centerOnScroll: 'true',
        onComplete: function() {
            $('#fancybox-frame').load(function() {
                $('#fancybox-content').height($(this).contents().find('body').height() + 0);
            });
        }
});
```

zend controller:

```
public function loginFormAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    //$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');

    $loginForm = new Application_Form_UserLogin();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        /************ Login Form ************/
        if ($loginForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->createRow($loginForm->getValues()); 
            $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->fetchRowByFields(array('email' => $email, 'hash' => $password));

            if($user) 
            {
                Zend_Session::rememberMe(86400 * 14);
                Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($user);
                $this->getHelper('redirector')->gotoRoute(array(), 'invite');
                return;
            } 
            else {
                // Error message
                $this->view->errorMsg = "<b>password</b> - invalid, please try again! *";
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            // something
        }
    }
    $this->view->loginForm = $loginForm;
}
```

html form:

```
<body>  
    <div id="login" class="">
        <div id="login_lb_content">
            <h1 class="content_title colorset_orange">Login to your account</h1>
            <form action="" method="post" name="loginForm" id="login-form">
                <table><tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="content_sub_title colorset_gray">Your email address</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->loginForm->email->getValue(); ?>" /></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td width="120" class="content_sub_title colorset_gray">Your password</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;" class="colorset_gray small_font">(It was sent to your email address when you registered)</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $this->loginForm->password->getValue(); ?>" /></td>
                </tr><tr>                       
                    <td><a id="inline-retreive" href="#retreive" class="content_sub_title colorset_orange fblink">Retreive my password</a></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" id="btn_login" name="login" value="" /></td>
                </tr></table>

                <div id="login-error" style="color:red">
                <?php if ($this->loginForm->getErrors()): ?>
                    <?php foreach($this->loginForm->getMessages() as $field => $messages): ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $field; ?></strong>
                        <?php foreach($messages as $messageKey => $message): ?>
                            - <?php echo $message; ?><br />
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->errorMsg; ?><br />
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div><!-- END div[login panel] -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it does work properly. It refreshes inside fancybox because it is an `iframe` and it would be the same like embedding the form in an `iframe` tag (only the iframe will be reloaded but not the parent page)

You would need to use the method `parent.$.fancybox.close();` called within your form after the it has been successfully submitted .... or you could use `onsubmit` in the form tag :

```
<form onsubmit="parent.$.fancybox.close();" ...
```

... then, in your custom script add the option :

```
"onClosed": function(){
  parent.location.reload(true);
}
```

to refresh the parent page.

**NOTE** : I am assuming that you are using fancybox v1.3.4 because the API options in your code above.

Comment: Thanks for that, it works, but now it doesn't validate, it submit right away....you think I should use ajax???

Comment: @user1876353 : build a function in zend that validates if the form has been successfully submitted, then call `parent.$.fancybox.close();`

Comment: how can you call parent.$.fancybox.close(); in the controller action??

Comment: `<?php if(condition){?><script>parent.$.fancybox.close();</script><?php };?>` I guess.